# How to add pair to anonymous object using function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass `menu: "#menu"` to the anonymous object using `chWidth()`.

How can i do this?

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({verticalCentered: false}, chWidth());


    function chWidth() {
        if ($(window).width()) {
            return {menu: "#menu"}
        }
    }
```

so it should ends up like this:
    { 
     verticalCentered: false, 
     menu: "#menu"
    }

How should the return statement be? I get an error if i try `return menu:"#menu"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `return` statement is fine as is.

If you're using jQuery you can use [`$.extend`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) like this:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage($.extend({verticalCentered: false}, chWidth()));
```

Alternatively you can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) like this (but you'll lose support on older browsers):

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage(Object.assign({verticalCentered: false}, chWidth()));
```

Comment: Should you not mark it as dupe instead?

Comment: @Rajesh I didn't do a check for dupes - didn't know if it was or wasn't. Figured the 20 seconds it took to add an answer was just as easy as searching for duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

First, your `chWidth` has incosistent return points.
You should return same type(object) in else branch.

To combine objects, you can to use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method:

```js
function chWidth(cond) {
  // use cond for emulate both boolean cases
  if (cond) {
      return {menu: "#menu"};
  } else {
    return {};
  }
}

console.log(Object.assign({verticalCentered: false}, chWidth()));
console.log(Object.assign({verticalCentered: false}, chWidth(true)));
```